# Why do I get a large space when I use \lastbox here?

Tags: spacing, boxes, paragraphs

I'm trying to understand `\lastbox` and `\unhbox` and friends. Unfortunately, it's a bit above my `TeX` pay grade…

Why do I get a large space in this example?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newbox\linebox
\begin{document}
\vbox{%
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vel
  leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus. \textcolor{red}{why space?}\par
  \setbox\linebox\lastbox
  \unskip\unpenalty
  \noindent
  \unhbox\linebox
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vel
  leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have `\rightskip` and `\parfillskip` in the box which you want to remove after unhboxing.

[image]

(You may want to add a word-space instead, but here I just remove)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newbox\linebox
\begin{document}
\vbox{%
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vel
  leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus. \textcolor{red}{why space?}\par
  \setbox\linebox\lastbox
  \unskip\unpenalty
  \noindent
  \unhbox\linebox\unskip\unskip
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vel
  leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus.}
\end{document}
```

Here's the final part of the log when doing `\showbox\linebox` after having set it to `\lastbox` (it is be necessary to give a high value to `\showboxbreadth` and `\showboxdepth`, which LaTeX sets to –1):

```
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 f
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 a
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 u
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 c
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 i
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 b
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 u
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 s
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 .
.\glue 4.44444 plus 4.99997 minus 0.37036
.\pdfcolorstack 0 push {1 0 0 rg 1 0 0 RG}
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 w
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 h
.\kern-0.27779
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 y
.\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 s
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 p
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 a
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 c
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 ?
.\pdfcolorstack 0 pop
.\penalty 10000
.\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
```

Comment: Yes, that makes sense! I was fiddling with the value of `\parfilskip` and that affected things, but I couldn't work out why. Thank you!

Comment: Which shows why `\rightskip` glue is always inserted even if it is zero.

Comment: @egreg, thanks for adding the `\showbox` command. I notice also the `\penalty 10000` in there before the glue. I guess I should also add `\unpenalty` to get rid of that, right?

Comment: @DavidPurton Yes, you can do it as well, so a line break can be taken after the unboxed material, if you add some glue after it.